# Alamofire Encoding issue

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Creating a router using Alamofire to handle my API requests like so:

```
enum GoogleRouter: URLRequestConvertible {

case FetchCoordinatesFromPostcode(postcode: String)

static let baseURLString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?"

var method: HTTPMethod {
    switch self {
    case .FetchCoordinatesFromPostcode:
        return .get
    }
}

var path: String {
    switch self {
    case .FetchCoordinatesFromPostcode(let postcode):
        return "?address=\(postcode)&key=MY_KEY"
    }
}

func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {
    let url = try GoogleRouter.baseURLString.asURL()
    print(url)
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url.appendingPathComponent(path))
    urlRequest.httpMethod = method.rawValue

    switch self {
    default:
        break
    }

    return urlRequest
}

}
```

Problem is that, the URL to fetch the lat long from the postcode I'm entering has a `?` in the middle of the URL.  No matter where I seem to place the question mark, whether at the end of the `baseURLString` or the beginning of the `path`, the `?` seems to become encoding thus sending a request to the wrong url (I've inserted both in the code above)

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it like this

```
enum GoogleRouter: URLRequestConvertible {

//the base url (REMOVE THE ? MARK)
static let baseURLString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json"

//the router
case FetchCoordinatesFromPostcode([String:Any])  //set the case like this

var method: HTTPMethod {
    switch self {
    case .FetchCoordinatesFromPostcode:
        return .get
    }
}

//WE Won't be needing path, so lets just remove it

/*var path: String {
    switch self {
    case .FetchCoordinatesFromPostcode(let postcode):
        return "?address=\(postcode)&key=MY_KEY"
    }
}*/

func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {
    //get the url from string
    let url = try GoogleRouter.baseURLString.asURL()

    //prepare urlrequest
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = method.rawValue

    switch self {
    case .FetchCoordinatesFromPostcode(let parameters):
        urlRequest = try URLEncoding.queryString.encode(urlRequest, with: parameters)
    }

    return urlRequest
}

}

func testCall() {
let parameters = ["addres":"myAddress","key":"MY_KEY"]
let request = Alamofire.request(GoogleRouter.FetchCoordinatesFromPostcode(parameters))
request.validate().responseJSON { (response) in
    //Do The Thing
}

}
```

Comment: No different to the original result

Comment: With some tweaking I made use of your answer and got ther ein the end :) thanks

Comment: It will be best if you could also post the changed code. It may help others